# Differentiation between views when using UItouch

Tags: ios, xcode, view, coordinates, uitouch

I'm currently working on a project in iOS where I want the UItouch command to only send co-ordinates out when it's over a certain "image". I've got the co-ordinates outputting using UItouch but am not able to do this for just one specific area.

To my knowledge, the only way to do this is with views. So I've made a new view within my mainview, and from there I have problems and can't seem to get it working.

Has anyone done this before/can give me any advice on this?

PS - I'm using Xcode 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very confusing:  UITouch is a class, not a command.  What is "image" (in quotes?) - a UIImageView?  An image drawn in the mainview?  What are your "problems"?  Please post code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches  anyObject];
if (touch.view==yourImageView) {
    //Coordinate code
}

}
```

EDIT: Or try using the `UITapGestureRecognizer`

In your interface add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
```

then in your viewDidLoad add this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapMethod)];
tapped.delegate=self;
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

then in your viewController add these 2 methods

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (touch.view==yourImageView) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)tapMethod {
    //Coordinate code
}
```

And make sure you have `[yourImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

Comment: I think you're along the right lines but it's still detecting touches outside the UIImageview.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys. Figured it out in the end with help from your examples.